# Excluding entries based on Date Field Type

Tags: date, date-field-filter

Im wondering if anyone can help me figure out if this is possible.

I have entries that have a Date Field Type and I want to hide entries that have expired passed the date set in the Date Field Type not the entry-date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can't you just use expire date field under the date tab? and show_expired="no"

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can to show me.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/_user_guide_src_ee/_images/publish_cal.png

Comment: Well, Ive set up a custom field which is a Date field. I set the date in the custom field to, lets say 10.10.14. I want the entry to show up to that date and then after that date be removed. I know I can do this by using the entry date and expired but can it be done using a the date custom field?

Comment: i guess you could put it in a conditional like this
{if '{custom_date_field}' => '{entry_date}'}{title}{/if}

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [EEvent Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/eevent-helper) extension to do this - it allows you to select "start" and "end" dates for entries, and clone those custom field dates to the Entry Date and Expiration Date respectively.